# Confirming the existence of a function related to a matrix

Tags: function-construction, matrix, linear-algebra

Is it possible to get an answer to the following question in *Mathematica*?

Let $M$ be a $n$ by $n$ matrix, is there a function $m:\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m_{ij}=m_{ji}$ and $m_{ij}=m_{i+2,j+2}$ for all $i$ and $j$.

I am new to *Mathematica*  and interested whether such existential, abstract expressions can be solved in *Mathematica*.

Comment: If the dimension `n` is specified one can use FindInstance to solve for the m_i,j.

Comment: Sorry maybe it was not clear. I will enter the matrix M, so yes it'll be specified.

Comment: Now I'm confused. I was assuming the m_i,j are entries of your `M`. Is that not the case? (In particular, is your `M` a numeric matrix?) If so then I'm not clear as to what is the question.

Comment: Wait... you changed your question. I thought the $m_{ij}$ were entries in your matrix. Is that not the case? What relation does $M$ have with $f$?

Comment: They can be thought as the entries of the matrix, at the end of the day it's a function. I changed it to $f$ because it might be misunderstood that they are the actual entries of the matrix $M$. I try to understand your answer, thanks!

Comment: This does remain confusing, as @rm -rf notes. There seems to be no linkage between `f` and `M`. I willadd that, as worded, any constant function will satisfy those equations.

Comment: I am just getting used to this writing system, my apologies!

Comment: So now it's no longer $i+2,j+2$, but all possible $i,j,k,l$? You should formulate your problem correctly  before posting instead of changing it every 5 minutes... else it is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I totally agree with you, it's my first time and it's completely my mistake! Should I edit it to the version as you answered, and I open a new question? btw. your answer is really helpful for me to understand, thanks!

Comment: Ok, no worries :) I would revert this to the original version (which was properly specified). If you were to start a new question, I would suggest doing so after studying my answer (and the documentation for the functions used) and then try to solve your general problem. If you _then_ get stuck, you can ask a new one (who knows, maybe it can be extended very easily and you won't have to ask a question). Another suggestion would be to use Daniel's comment above and try `FindInstance`. People always like it when prior effort is shown (and my answer should guide you). Welcome to the site, btw! :)

Comment: Okay please revert the question.. Thank you and Daniel for helping!!

Comment: The requirements on $f$ imply $m_{ij} + m_{ji}$ = $f(i,j)+f(j,i)$ = $2f(i,j)$, giving a unique solution--as well as a formula for it--if any solution exists at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The good thing about programming with *Mathematica* is that you can move from conceptual problems like the one described to getting a solution pretty easily. Since you're new to *Mathematica*, let's walk this through step by step:

> **1.** Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ matrix

This one's easy:

```
ℳ[n_Integer] := Array[m, {n, n}]
ℳ[5] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

> **2.** A function $m:\ \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m_{ij}=m_{ji}$

In other words, we don't care about the order $i,j$ or $j,i$ — we can achieve this simply by making `m` have the attribute `Orderless`.

```
SetAttributes[m, Orderless]
ℳ[5] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Compare this output with the one above.

> **3.** A function $m:\ \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m_{ij}=m_{i+2,j+2}$

Here, we can use `RSolve` to solve for the relation `m[i,j] == m[i+2,j+2]`:

```
RSolve[m[i, j] == m[2 + i, 2 + j], m[i, j], {i, j}]
(* {{m[i, j] -> C[1][-2 i + 2 j] + (-1)^i C[2][-2 i + 2 j]}} *)
```

What this solution says is that $m$ can be a function of the form

$$m: (i,j)\mapsto C_1(i,j) +(-1)^iC_2(i,j)$$

where the $C_i$ are constant functions (`C` denotes a constant in *Mathematica*).

Now putting all of these together, we can do:

```
Block[{m, p, q},
    SetAttributes[m, Orderless];
    m[i_, j_] := p + (-1)^i q;
    ℳ[5]
] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

where `p` and `q` are constants you can choose.

Comment: Why do you define `m` as `p + (-1)^i q` instead of `p[j - i] + (-1)^i q[j - i]`?

Comment: @ssch It's a constant function

Comment: ah right, never seen `C[i][x]` in a result before. Nice solution!